# EF one to many with linking table

Tags: entity-framework, one-to-many, relationship

I'm new to Entity Framework and I'm struggling with the database created from my POCO classes. I have a generic class that looks like this:

```
public class Comment
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Text { get; set; }
   public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

And comments can be added to many objects, lets say for example Person and Vehicle, so I will have these classes

```
public class Person
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Vehicle
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

When EF generates my database it adds a Person_Id and Vehicle_Id, which to me is incorrect because:
a) It suggests that a comment relates to a person AND a vehicle, where it should really be a "free standing" object
b) Comments can be added to future objects which will require a table change.

How can I get EF to rather use a linking table for this?

(Note: I cannot and do not want to add navigation properties to the Comment class as that will require a class change everytime a new object needs comments, and my comment class is in my generic library, unrelated to people or vehicles)

I have found this article, but I'm struggling to get my answer from it: http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/05/17/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-6-many-valued-associations.aspx

Answer (score 0):

EF is generating `Person_Id` and `Vehicle_Id` columns on the `Comment` table, which are nullable. That means that the Comments can be linked to a Person OR a Vehicle OR both a Person and a Vehicle OR Neither. So it *is* really a "free standing" object.

The model you are probably looking for uses [inheritance](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx).

```
public class Comment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
}

public class VehicleComment : Comment
{
    public int VehicleID;
}

public class PersonComment : Comment
{
    public int PersonID;
}


public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<PersonComment> Comments { get; set; }
}

public class Vehicle
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<VehicleComment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

EF will default to table-per-hierarchy inheritance. This will create a table similar to the one you have already, but with a "Discriminator" column. You can then work with a `DbSet<VehicleComment>` directly rather than having to query `DbSet<Comment>`...`Where(x => x.Vehicle_Id != null)` to get comments about Vehicles.

Yes, comments added to future objects will require a table change but that isn't exactly a hardship when using Code First. And writing code gets much simpler because you are not going via some kind of linking entity.

**EDIT**
The change that happens when you add a new Entity with a relationship to Comments is that another foreign key column is added to the Comments table to model that relationship. Adding a nullable column to an existing table is probably as simple a schema change as you can get. As for change control, you are adding a table for the new entity anyway - so you've got a migration file that contains a few extra lines of code.

Also, having a linking table would mean giving up foreign key constraints, cascade deletes etc. would it not?

```
public class FooComment : Comment
{
   //FooID means one more column in the table
   public int FooID;
}

public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<FooComment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, my concern about changing the table in future is not so much difficulty related but more change control related, this is actually an over simplification of my requirement, in my app this could have large implementation challenges. Plus from a schema perspective I think its wrong to have to update a generic entity for every entity that may reference it, one could argue in both ways but I don't like it. I will test your suggestion but if it will create a PersonComment table and a VehicleComment table it will probably not work for me

Comment: @AdriaanDavel Table Per Hierarchy creates one table for all the comments - similar to the one you have already but with a "Discriminator" column. See my edit for what actually changes when using TPH.